# Rodrigues formula for Chebyshev rational functions.

Tags: calculus

Could you calculate a [Rodrigues formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula) for the [Chebyshev rational functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_rational_functions) defined by
$$T_n\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$$

where $T_n$ is a [Chebyshev polynomial.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)

Comment: What do you mean by *Rodrigues representation*? And what have you attempted?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It is a *well known* form of formula that represents the orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio There is a Rodrigues formula for all orthogonal polynomials.They are obtained by integrating by parts the orthogonality relation. The question here is whether there is a similar formula for these rational orthogonal system. One could take the Rodrigues formula for the Chebyshev's and compose with $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ but that is kind of cheating. Ideally  it would be a formula like $a_n D^n G(x)$ for some $G$, with $D$ the derivative.

Comment: If we set $A_n=T_n\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$, then such rational functions are orthogonal with respect to the inner product $$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f\cdot g}{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}\,dx $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Rational functions.

Comment: @Pp.. : all right, anyway, that is not the point. Now we have found the inner product for which they are orthogonal. Integration by parts should give the Rodrigues representation, right?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, for the case of polynomials successive derivatives turn them into zero. So, exactly the same procedure is not going to work here. That is why I was emphasizing that it is rational functions now.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably **not** the sort of formula you are looking for but let me write it for reference of how Rodrigues formulas for the classic polynomials are computed. Perhaps, perhaps not, the procedure can be adapted for these rational functions.

We have a Rodrigues formula for Chebyshev polynomials. Let us deduce it.

Chebyshev polynomials are (a particular case of the Jacobi polynomials) orthogonal with respect to

$$\int_{-1}^{1}T_m(x)T_n(x)K(x)dx$$

where $K(x)=(x^2-1)^{1/2}$.

Let us do the following (integrate by parts many times)

$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^{1}\left((x^2-1)^nK(x)\right)^{(n)}x^mdx&=-\int_{-1}^{1}\left((x^2-1)^nK(x)\right)^{(n-1)}mx^{m-1}dx\\&=...=(-1)^mm!\int_{-1}^{1}\left((x^2-1)^nK(x)\right)^{(n-m)}dx\\&=(-1)^mm!\left((x^2-1)^nK(x)\right)^{(n-m-1)}|_{-1}^{1}\\&=0\end{align}$$

This means that

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{K(x)}\left((x^2-1)K(x)\right)^{(n)}x^mK(x)dx=0$$

This means that $\frac{1}{K(x)}\left((x^2-1)K(x)\right)^{(n)}$ is orthogonal to all powers $m<n$. This implies that it is an orthogonal system with respect to the product above. By uniqueness, if we adjust the leading coefficient we should get the Chebyshev polynomials. From this it follows the formula

> $$T_n(x)=(x^2-1)^{-1/2}\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left((x^2-1)^n(x^2-1)^{1/2}\right)$$

You could compose with $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ to get **a** formula for $T_n\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$ but this composition would appear after the derivatives. This is not the way Rodrigues formulas look like.

Comment: One should probably change notations T to more standard U for the second kind of Chebychev polynomial? Also I found that more standard normalisation is
   $$U_n(x)= \frac{(n+1) \frac{\partial ^n\left(\sqrt{1-x^2} \left(x^2-1\right)^n\right)}{\partial x^n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2} (2 n+1)\text{!!}}$$

Comment: @NikolayGromov actually, this might be a mistake in the sign, not in the notation: $U$ and $T$ differ by the sign in the exponent inside the definition of $K(x)$. To get actual $T$ one has to define $K(x)=(x^2-1)^{-1/2}$. In this case the full normalized formula will be $$T_n(x)= \frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)!!}(x^2-1)^{1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}(x^2-1)^{n-1/2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let we just follow the approach in the paragraph *Rodrigues' formula* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_orthogonal_polynomials). By setting
$$ A_n(x)=T_n\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\tag{1} $$
and $x=\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}=\cot^2\frac{\theta}{2}$ we have:
$$ A_n\left(\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\right) = \cos(n\theta)\tag{2} $$
and by differentiating two times both sides with respect to $\theta$ we get:
$$2(2+\cos\theta)\,A_n'(x)+4x\, A_n''(x) = -n^2 \cos(n\theta) = -n^2 A_n(x)$$
or:
$$ 4x\,A_n''+2\frac{1+3x}{1+x}\,A_n'+n^2 A_n = 0\tag{3} $$
and the associated functions with this Sturm-Liouville-type differential equation are $R(x)=(1+x)\sqrt{x}$ and $W(x)=\frac{1+x}{4\sqrt{x}}$. This gives that $A_n$ should be proportional to:

$$\frac{1}{W(x)}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(W(x)\cdot(4x)^n\right)$$
or to:
$$ \frac{4^n\sqrt{x}}{1+x}\cdot\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left((1+x)\cdot x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\right).\tag{4}$$
However, we can notice that the condition on the coefficient of $A_n'$ in $(3)$ to be linear *is not* met, so, if $(4)$ is not the Rodrigues representation for $A_n$, this set of functions does not have a Rodrigues representation.

Comment: @Jack How do you get that $A_n$ is proportional to that formula? A proof, for orthogonal polynomials, is the argument I wrote in my answer. The idea is that you show that that iterated derivative thing satisfies the orthogonality relation, and are polynomials.

Comment: @Pp..: I just followed the paragraph Rodrigues' formula by computing the ausiliary functions $Q(x),L(x),W(x),R(x)$. However, here $L(x)$ is not a linear function, hence the usual formula above $(4)$ does not apply. The point is that we have a Rodrigues' formula only if the Sturm-Liouville differential equation satisfies some constraints, and this is not the case.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, notice that the equation not being of that form doesn't imply that you can't get solutions of the form $a_nG(x)d^n(F_n(x))$ for some functions $F,G$ and constants $a_n$. Actually, now that I think, this might be a way to find one, or prove there is none. What about we put this form into the differential equation and impose the coefficients it has?

Comment: @Pp..: The issue here is that $W(x)x^n$ is not a $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ function, like it is for Laguerre polynomials (for which $W(x)=x^\alpha e^{-x}$), so integration by parts does not lead anywhere.